# Send picture to Page Event

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, post, file-upload, curl

I've seen this question asked and answered all over the web, however none of the answers have worked for me. Either it must mean they're outdated or incorrect.

Basicly I've managed to make a script which creates a new event with the right dates, name, description etc. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to send the event's picture so it gets upload to the event. I've tried parsing

```
'file.jpg' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'
'file' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'
'@file.jpg' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'
'@ile.jpg' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'
'photo' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'
'picture' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'
'source' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'
```

and none seems to do the trick. What am I missing?

On previous examples sending it as a post-array alongside all other values would be enough.

Are there any new terms to this or something? Yet again I find no explanation on [Facebooks documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'file' => '@/path/to/file.jpg'` is the correct format.

In cURL directly it would be

```
curl -F 'access_token=xxx' \
-F 'name=Sandbox' \
-F 'description=Nothing to see here' \
-F 'start_time=2013-12-01T12:00:00+0000' \
-F 'file=@/path/to/your.jpg' \
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/events
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. My mistake I think was to parse `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($arr_query));` instead of without `http_build_query()`. I should've sent it as an array instead of a string, and it helped to know which key value to send.